# Requested Thread name missing when is the only one

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, lua, vscode-debugger

If only one thread is returned in the response of a DAP 'threads' request its name is missing in the call stack view. The call stack of that thread is shown directly in the view.

```
{
    {id = 1, name = "Main Thread(Global)"}
}
```

When there are multiple threads listed every thread shows its name and its call stack is below it.

Can I somehow force showing the name in the scenario with the single thread too?

Thank you